# NFS not registering with RPCBIND . MAC OS Catalina

Tags: mac, catalina, nfs

I'm having a problem with NFS on macOS Catalina. I created a `/etc/exports` and checked with `nfsd checkexports`. I started NFS and made sure it running with `nfsd status`. I gave NFS 5 mins to get breakfast then type in `rpcinfo` and all I see is **rpcbind** **status** and **nlockmgr**. There is no NFS anywhere.

I also checked with `lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`, and I see that `nfsd` is listening on TCP * :997 998 and 2049. I did restart nfsd with both restart and update tag but NFS is still not showing up in rpcinfo.

Did Catalina change anything regarding NFS? Can anyone point me in the right direction??

Comment: Did you try to connect via NFS (from another computer), does it work?

Comment: showmount -e not even working on locahost since nfs is not showing up as registered service when I ran rpcinfo.showmount -e
showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: localhost: RPC failed:: RPC: Procedure unavailable